# Apache Spark SQL UDT Kryo serialization, Unable to find class

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-types, kryo

I want to introduce custom type for SchemaRDD, I'm following [this](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/test/ExamplePointUDT.scala) example
But I'm having Kryo Serialization issues, here is stack trace:

```
    org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 6.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: 
    Lost task 0.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 22, localhost): 
    com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Unable to find class: com.gis.io.GeometryWritable
    Serialization trace:
    value (org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.MutableAny)
    values (org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.SpecificMutableRow)
       at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readName(DefaultClassResolver.java:138)
       at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readClass(DefaultClassResolver.java:115)
       at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClass(Kryo.java:610)
       at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer$ObjectField.read(FieldSerializer.java:599)
       at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:221)
       at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:732)
       at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultArraySerializers$ObjectArraySerializer.read(DefaultArraySerializers.java:338)
       at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultArraySerializers$ObjectArraySerializer.read(DefaultArraySerializers.java:293)
       at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:651)
       at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer$ObjectField.read(FieldSerializer.java:605)
       at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:221)
       at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:732)
       at com.twitter.chill.Tuple2Serializer.read(TupleSerializers.scala:42)
       at com.twitter.chill.Tuple2Serializer.read(TupleSerializers.scala:33)
       at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:732)
       at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoDeserializationStream.readObject(KryoSerializer.scala:142)
       at org.apache.spark.serializer.DeserializationStream$$anon$1.getNext(Serializer.scala:133)
       at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:71)
       at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:32)
       at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
       at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:32)
       at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:39)
       at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
       at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.HashedRelation$.apply(HashedRelation.scala:80)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.ShuffledHashJoin$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(ShuffledHashJoin.scala:46)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.ShuffledHashJoin$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(ShuffledHashJoin.scala:45)
       at org.apache.spark.rdd.ZippedPartitionsRDD2.compute(ZippedPartitionsRDD.scala:88)
       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:263)
       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:230)
       at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:263)
       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:230)
       at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:263)
       at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:61)
       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:228)
       at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:263)
       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:230)
       at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:263)
       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:230)
       at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:263)
       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:230)
       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:68)
       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:56)
       at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:196)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gis.io.GeometryWritable
       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
       at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
       at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
       at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readName(DefaultClassResolver.java:136)
       ... 52 more
```

Where *com.gis.io.GeometryWritable* is my Custom class for which I'm creating UDT, which is present in the APP jar.
I've tried as disused [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/aureliusgraphs/iqDbeLJsGsg) in Google groups also by changing spark default serializer from kryo to Java. But it doesn't help me out.
Any Suggestions ?? If I'm missing something? Following are my classes:

```
    @SQLUserDefinedType(udt = classOf[GeometryUDT])
    class GeometryWritable(var _geometry: Geometry) extends Writable with Serializable {

       def geometry = _geometry
       def geometry_=(geometry: Geometry) = _geometry = geometry

       def this() = this(null)

       override def write(dataOutput: DataOutput) : Unit = {}
       override def readFields(dataInput: DataInput) : Unit = {}
       @throws(classOf[IOException])
       private def writeObject(stream: ObjectOutputStream): Unit = {}
       @throws(classOf[IOException])
       private def readObject(stream: ObjectInputStream): Unit = {}
    }

    class GeometryUDT extends UserDefinedType[GeometryWritable] with Serializable {

      override def sqlType: DataType = ArrayType(ByteType)
      override def serialize(obj: Any): Array[Byte] = {}
      override def deserialize(datum: Any): GeometryWritable = {}
      override def userClass: Class[GeometryWritable] = classOf[GeometryWritable]

   }
```

This is how I'm using it.

```
    val rdd = sc.textFile(args(0)).map(
    line => {
      val point = new Point
      point.setY(line.split(" ")(0).toDouble)
      point.setX(line.split(" ")(1).toDouble)
      Row.fromSeq(Seq(new GeometryWritable(point)))
     })
     val schema = StructType(Seq(StructField("Geometry",new GeometryUDT, true)))

     val schemaRDD = sqlContext.applySchema(rdd, schema).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
```

**EDITED:**
Actually I've figured it out that custom UDT works fine if I use only one RDD (table). The issue arises when we join two or more RDDs. According to [this](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/SPARKC-23), its is a bug when we use custom ROW and use JOIN. Any clues ??

Comment: Well, the exception does not seem to be about your code, rather, it seems unable to FIND the class at all. Check if you have the right imports and package definitions or build.

Comment: This exception occurs when we use JOIN, as this bug is tracked here ...
https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/SPARKC-23